# Why does the condition not work when changing the selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a `select` changes, the text should change. [Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/83qnm3am/2/)

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  function funcFormCalc() {
    var s1_is_1 = $("#s1").value === '1',
        s1_is_2 = $("#s1").value === '2';

    var s2_is_1 = $("#s2").value === '1',
        s2_is_2 = $("#s2").value === '2';
        
    $('#myForm').onchange = function() {
      
      if (s1_is_1 && s2_is_1) {
        $('#result').html('result 1');
      } else if (s1_is_2 && s2_is_1) {
        $('#result').html('result 2');
      } else if (s1_is_1 && s2_is_2) {
        $('#result').html('result 3');
      } else {
        $('#result').html('result 4');
      }

    };
  }
  funcFormCalc();

})(window.jQuery);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
  <label for="s1">
    Tree Number
    <select id="s1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </label><br>
  <label for="s2">
    Tree Height
    <select id="s2">
      <option value="1">1 story house</option>
      <option value="2">2 story house</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <div id="result">Result Displays Here</div>
</form>
```

Why does the result text not change when a selection changes?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the meaning of [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reduce your code to the **minimum** that demonstrates the error, provide sample input, expected output and the actual output along with any error messages.

Comment: Why do you use `document.getElementById` with jQuery?

Comment: @PeterMader—the OP hasn't used jQuery for anything, it seems to be there for show.

Comment: Because you're not changing the `selectXVariantY` values

Comment: @RobG Thank you. Has removed superfluous. I can not understand why the condition does not work when changing option select.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your code to make it more concise. And, since you are using jQuery, I changed your code to use it. If you want to change it back, simply compare the changes I made with the original. I also edited the title and post to fix grammar and syntax issues. Next time, please only include relevant code, if you want your question answered fast. Also, clearly state what you are seeing, and what you should be seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `selectVariant` booleans to determine which value to show, however these variables are only being calculated once on load. You probably meant to have the calculations in your `onchange` function.

Also your values do not match the options for `select2`.

```
<option value="1 story house">1 story house</option>
<option value="2 story house">2 story house</option>
<option value="3 story house +">3 story house +</option>
```

*-- See snippet at bottom for original answer with some additional refactoring. --*

**EDIT: You completely changed the code in your question since my first answer...**

Though my answer is the same. You need to recalculate `selectVariant1`, `selectVariant2`, `select2Variant1`, and `select2Variant2` inside the `onchange` method.

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  function funcFormCalc() {
    var formCalc = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc')[0],
      formCalcResult = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc__result')[0],

      selectHowManyTrees = document.getElementById('selectHowManyTrees'),
      selectApproximateHeightTree = document.getElementById('selectApproximateHeightTree');
      
    formCalc.onchange = function() {

    var selectVariant1 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '1',
      selectVariant2 = selectHowManyTrees.value === '2';

    var select2Variant1 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '1',
      select2Variant2 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value === '2';    
 
      if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 1';
      } else if (selectVariant2 && select2Variant1) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 2';
      } else if (selectVariant1 && select2Variant2) {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'variant text 3';      
      } else {
        formCalcResult.innerHTML = 'for all variants';
      }

    };
  }
  funcFormCalc();



})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2C2D2C;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.form-calc {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.form-calc__item {
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.form-calc__label {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.form-calc__select-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before,
.form-calc__select-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before {
  top: 16.5px;
  border-width: 0 3.5px 4px 3.5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
}

.form-calc__select-container:after {
  bottom: 16.5px;
  border-width: 4px 3.5px 0 3.5px;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.form-calc__select {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  padding: 0 7px;
  color: #2C2D2C;
}

.form-calc__select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.form-calc__select option {
  padding: 3px 7px;
  border: none;
}

.form-calc__result {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.form-calc__result-subtext {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.form-calc__submit {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 170px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background: #42BF8D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.form-calc__submit:hover,
.form-calc__submit:focus,
.form-calc__submit:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2F8B66;
}

.form-calc__submit:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-calc" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__label">Label 1</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select1" id="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>        
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__label">Label 2</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select2" id="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1">1 story house</option>
        <option value="2">2 story house</option>       
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <div class="form-calc__result">variant text 1</div>    
  </div>  
</form>
```

**Edit 2: Responding to question in comment.**

> Excuse me! Not a big question. How would you solve this problem? (other logic).

This is a pretty opinionated question, so this answer is just my opinion. In general I think you have a pretty decent solution.

Your problem is essentially:
***Display a result dependent on a combination of inputs.***

So there needs to be some way to calculate a value based on the inputs. It would be best if you could do this mathematically, like `value1 + value2 + value3 = result`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible for your problem, but if you are able to do a slight design change then you could try this alternative:

1. Modify your form so each option has a `low-value` and `high-value`.

```
<select name="select1" id="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__select">
    <option low-value="20" high-value="30" selected>1</option>
    <option low-value="30" high-value="40">2</option>
    <option low-value="40" high-value="50">3</option>
    <option low-value="50" high-value="60">4</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__select">
    <option low-value="100" high-value="180" story house">1 story house</option>
    <option low-value="170" high-value="300" story house">2 story house</option>
    <option low-value="220" high-value="600" story house +">3 story house +</option>
</select>
```

2. Sum up all the selected `low-value` and all the selected `high-value` to calculate the result.

```
var low = 0, high = 0;
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc__select');
for(var s of selects) {
   var selectedOption = s.options[ s.selectedIndex ];
   low += selectedOption.getAttribute('low-value');
   high += selectedOption.getAttribute('high-value');
}
```

3. Display this as a range for your result.

```
formCalcResult.innerHTML = '$' + low + ' - $' + high;
```

or with [ES6 string interpolation](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation)

```
formCalcResult.innerHTML = `$${low} - $${high}`;
```

Now it may be that you cannot do this, and that there is no way to mathematically calculate the result. In this scenario you are forced to find a way to link a combination of inputs to a result, which is what you did using a bunch of booleans.

How could you do it better? **A database.**

The ideal place for storing data relationships is in a database. Then your application can dynamically display all the options and results. This will allow you whenever there is a change to a value you just update the data rather than updating the entire application. It is also a very readable way of storing the different option combinations. For example you could have a table that looks like this:

```
NumberOfTreesId | TreeHeightId | JobTypeId | LocationPropertyId |Result
1               | 1            | 1         | 1                  | '$250 - $610'
1               | 1            | 1         | 2                  | '$350 - $825'
```

This example resembles SQL, but you could do something very similar using a non-relational database if you wanted.

Of course, using a database adds a lot of complexity to your application and you are just doing a JS tutorial, so definitely overkill. So after all that I would say design-wise your code is perfectly fine. There is a lot of ways you could refactor to make it more readable and less code, but in the end the concept will be the same.

There are a lot of ways this could be written differently, here is one way:

```js
(function($) {

  'use strict';
  
  var results = [ ];
  
  function addResult(s1, s2, s3, s4, r) {
     results.push({
        select1 : s1,
        select2 : s2,
        select3 : s3,
        select4 : s4,
        result : r
     });
  }
  
  var defaultResult = '$450 - $750';
  addResult('1', '1', '1', '1', '$250 - $610');
  addResult('1', '1', '1', '2', '$350 - $825');
  addResult('1', '1', '1', '3', '$250 - $610');
  addResult('1', '2', '1', '1', '$425 - $1200');
  addResult('1', '2', '1', '2', '$546 - $1620');
  addResult('1', '2', '1', '3', '$420 - $1200');
  addResult('1', '3', '1', '1', '$750 - $1800');
  addResult('1', '3', '1', '2', '$900 - $2000');
  addResult('2', '1', '1', '1', '$500 - $850');
  addResult('2', '1', '1', '2', '$650 - $1000');
  addResult('2', '1', '1', '3', '$500 - $850');  

  function funcFormCalc() {
    var formCalc = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc')[0],
      formCalcResult = document.getElementsByClassName('form-calc__result')[0],
 
      selectHowManyTrees = document.getElementById('selectHowManyTrees'),
      selectApproximateHeightTree = document.getElementById('selectApproximateHeightTree'),
      selectJobType = document.getElementById('selectJobType'),
      selectLocationProperty = document.getElementById('selectLocationProperty');

    
    formCalc.onchange = function() {
    
      var s1 = selectHowManyTrees.value,
          s2 = selectApproximateHeightTree.value,
          s3 = selectJobType.value,
          s4 = selectLocationProperty.value;
      
      var text = defaultResult;
      for(var result of results)
      {
         if(s1 === result.select1 &&
            s2 === result.select2 &&
            s3 === result.select3 &&
            s4 === result.select4) {
            text = result.result;
         }
      }
      
      formCalcResult.innerHTML = text;
      //console.log(`${s1} ${s2} ${s3} ${s4}`);
    };
  }
  funcFormCalc();



})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #2C2D2C;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.form-calc {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

.form-calc__item {
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.form-calc__label {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px 0 9px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.form-calc__select-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before,
.form-calc__select-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-calc__select-container:before {
  top: 16.5px;
  border-width: 0 3.5px 4px 3.5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
}

.form-calc__select-container:after {
  bottom: 16.5px;
  border-width: 4px 3.5px 0 3.5px;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.form-calc__select {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  padding: 0 7px;
  color: #2C2D2C;
}

.form-calc__select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.form-calc__select option {
  padding: 3px 7px;
  border: none;
}

.form-calc__result {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.form-calc__result-subtext {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3E3F3E;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.form-calc__submit {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 170px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background: #42BF8D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.form-calc__submit:hover,
.form-calc__submit:focus,
.form-calc__submit:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2F8B66;
}

.form-calc__submit:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-calc" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__label">How many trees?</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select1" id="selectHowManyTrees" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__label">What is the approximate height of the tree?</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select2" id="selectApproximateHeightTree" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="1">1 story house</option>
        <option value="2">2 story house</option>
        <option value="3">3 story house +</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectJobType" class="form-calc__label">Job Type?</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select3" id="selectJobType" class="form-calc__select">
        <option value="-1">Complete tree removal</option>
        <option value="1">Tree Removal</option>
        <option value="2">Tree Prune</option>
        <option value="3">Palm Removal</option>
        <option value="4">Palm Prune</option>
        <option value="5">Arborist Report</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <label for="selectLocationProperty" class="form-calc__label">Trees location on your property?</label>

    <div class="form-calc__select-container">
      <select name="select4" id="selectLocationProperty" class="form-calc__select">
        <option selected>Front Yard</option>
        <option value="1">Access via a driveway (wide)</option>
        <option value="2">Access via a gate (narrow)</option>
        <option value="3">Vacant land</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">

    <div class="form-calc__result">$250 - $610</div>
    <div class="form-calc__result-subtext">Expected price range in Australia</div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-calc__item">
    <button type="submit" class="form-calc__submit">Request a quote</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do not correspond? Is it necessary to make a condition through the option?

Comment: `funcFormCalc` is only called once on document load. Inside there you are assigning another method to the change event of the form. That is this line: `formCalc.onchange = function() { ... }`. Inside that method is where you are trying to update `formCalcResult` using the `selectVariant` variables. However your mistake is that the value of these variables was calculated in `funcFormCalc`, which again, is only called once. You need to move those into the `formCalc.onchange` function, as I did in the snippets.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Excuse me! Not a big question. How would you solve this problem? (other logic).

Comment: [What to do when my question is answered..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You are talking about the whole problem in general?

Comment: I am modifying my answer to give a few alternative approaches. It will take me a little bit.

Comment: @ИванСимонов please see my updated answer. It is the result of drinking coffee at midnight. Hope it helps and good luck!